# red5 cpu usage is high

Tags: java, red5

I have done the press test for red5, but I found that when 100 clients request different live stream and play,(rtmp://xxx/xx) the cpu usage suddenly increases 30-40 percent.
Here is my cpu information.

> cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep name | cut -f2 -d: | uniq -c
>
> 1  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v2 @ 2.50GHz

I have removed extra business logic in my code, just auth method remains.

code in my application is:

```
    @Autowired
    private CasAuthHandler casAuthHandler;
    @Override
    public boolean start(IScope scope) {
        System.out.println("red5 start.....");
        return super.start(scope);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean appStart(IScope app) {
        log.warn("[app start] : " + app.getName());
        addListener(casAuthHandler);
        return super.appStart(app);
    }
```

In CasAuthHandler.java I did nothing but Thread.sleep(50) in appConnect method;

I hope someone can tell me what can I do to reduce the cpu usage. THKS

Comment: Remove your thread.sleep and test again. With such a call, it would seem that you're preventing the server from responding to clients.

Comment: I sorry but it seems does not work, and I changed the app name to the demo project (live),the cpu still seems too high. Not 30-40, even count to more than 60 percent(100 clients situation), Is there any suggestion can be used to relieve the problem?

Comment: I almost forgot something ,In my server, there is anther server, what the server do is that change h264 to rtmp, and post it to red5, so I adoubt that it is this to be blamed.

Comment: :(. What I guess is wrong...Because I login to my server and watch the mornitor I just found red5 occupied most cpu resources..

Comment: If I understand what you've posted, you're transcoding from h264? Not sure why you'd do that since flash supports it. Also transcoding is notorious for raising a cpu percentage.